# Line chart C# with time data on x axis

Tags: c#, .net, charts, series

I am working on line chart with .net & c# and I want to represent my data on a chart. Here is my data on X-Axis:

`string[] xAxisTime = {"07:34:56","07:34:57","07:34:58","07:34:59","07:35:00"}`.. etc.

My data onn Y-Axis:

`double[] yAxis = {14.00, 14.15, 14.16, 14.11}` ...etc

My problem is that I cant represent my data on the chart for those specific times strings.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What are you using for your UI (WinForms, WPF, UWP etc.)? Are you using a Chart library, if so which one? P.S I highly recommend you store an array of `DateTime` structs instead of strings.

Comment: I am using Winforms and I used various things such as Struct but still not working @MindSwipe

Comment: Did you a) declare the x-axis to be of type DataTime and b) add the data as Datetime fields (ie not as strings, as you show it)? You will __have to convert__ the strings to DateTime!!

Comment: Thank you guys, I have used `ToOADate()` format and it worked fine with me